# comparing different version in GIT

Tags: git

How to compare different version in Git. Let's assume my file got 10 version span across 4 branch, how do i compare one version of file with another version of file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

```
  git diff oneRef ANotherRef -- <path>
  git diff [options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>…]
```

with path the path of your file within the repo.

You can specify the commits in a *vast* number of ways:
See "SPECIFYING REVISIONS" in [git rev-parse](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) for more.

See also the [learngit site](http://learn.github.com/p/diff.html):

> If you want to compare a file between two snapshots - two versions of your project - instead of comparing a snapshot and the contents of your working directory, you can specify both versions on the command line:

```
$ git diff v1.0 v1.1 -- afile
```